# Question about an animated movie similar to Dr Strangelove: would it be on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to find the title of this animated movie, but I'm dubious if I can post the question in the main thread (the subject is similar to Dr Strangelove, so it is very borderline).
 So the question is if I can. There were some  clearly impossible things that happened, but usually happened for laughs.

I watched it in the early 90s, but probably it was a lot older (seemed '70s or early '80s).

The things I remember (I could only watch the final part):

- it was a parodistic cartoon
- The drawing style was similar to cartoons like Rocky and Bullwinkle (but no anthropomorphic animals), almost surely American
- The plot revolved about somebody trying to launch a nuclear missile to Soviet Union to start a nuclear war
- The day was saved by a sergeant (dressed as a clown), who found himself on the missile and, I think, a janitor
- During the crisis, the president of the USA continued to receive phone calls from his wife asking him to buy something before coming home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't identify an SFF-nal aspect of the series, then it would be off-topic for the site.

For example, you note a similarity in drawing style to (I assume) the original *Rocky and Bullwinkle* cartoons (appearing under a variety of names).

A *Rocky and Bullwinkle* story with the elements you site would not be on topic on this site (it's been established that the simple presence of anthropomorphic animals does not qualify a work as on-topic).

However, *Rocky and Bullwinkle* did

- occasionally feature aliens;
- include "Mr. Peabody and Sherman" shorts, involving time travel;
- include "Fractured Fairy Tales" shorts, which frequently (if not always) included fantasy elements.

If you can recall some such element, that would make a difference.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid it doesn't qualify then.. The most "sci-fi" subject is the underlying political fiction theme (trying to start a war by launching a missile against USSR), so I don't know if it is enough to be posted

Comment: If it's set in the 1950s or later, then I don't think that would qualify as a science fiction element.